# Set page numbering on specific pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, page, pagestyle, number

I have an article in which I'm using fancyhdr to make a header with section names and a footer on the right side of the pages.
However I want to remove the header on some specific pages while keeping the numbering. I've found \thispagestyle{plain} for this, which removes the header, but on these pages the page numbering goes to the middle instead keeping them on the right bottom.
How can have no header while having page numbering on the right bottom position? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short, compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1):

You can define another pagestyle, or redefine plain, with \fancypagestyle, and then use \thispagestyle{otherpagestyle}.

For example (not tested):

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}
```